# Get div id from select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good day. Please help me. I have a code:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="dynamic_selects">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select id="type" multiple>
                    <option value="63">1963</option>
                    <option value="64">1964</option>
                    <option value="65">1965</option>
                    <option value="66">1966</option>
                    <option value="67">1967</option>
                    <option value="68">1968</option>
                    <option value="69">1969</option>
                    <option value="70">1970</option>
                    <option value="71">1971</option>
                    <option value="72">1972</option>
                    <option value="73">1973</option>
                    <option value="74">1974</option>
                    <option value="75">1975</option>
                    <option value="76">1976</option>
                    <option value="77">1977</option>
                    <option value="78">1978</option>
                    <option value="79">1979</option>
                    <option value="80">1980</option>
                    <option value="81">1981</option>
                    <option value="82">1982</option>
                    <option value="83">1983</option>
                    <option value="84">1984</option>
                    <option value="85">1985</option>
                    <option value="86">1986</option>
                    <option value="87">1987</option>
                    <option value="89">1989</option>
                    <option value="91">1991</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="kind" disabled multiple>
                    <option value="0"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="category" onchange="showhideBlocks(this.value)" disabled multiple>
                    <option value="0"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I want to change this DIV id according to value from 'category':

```
<div id="iT635" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal"><img src="./docs/button-blyat.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

And href too, according to value from 'category' (values in another file, so I won't post this here)

Thanks.
P.S. One more question: how I can forbid multiple select, but leave selection boxes the same in columns?

Comment: So what have you got so far with the js?

Comment: I don't recommend changing element id's.  If you want to store the value in the div, use a `data` property.

Comment: Yes, @Smeegs is right -- you could also consider changing the classes,  instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="iT635" style="display:none;" class="someDiv"> ...
```

**JS:**

```
// Bind a change event on drop down!
$('#type').change(function(){
$('.someDiv').attr('id' , $('#type').val() );
});
```

and similar code for a:

```
$('.someDiv a').attr('href' , 'some-link#' + $('#type').val() );
```

Comment: how to add '.html' to formatted link? $('.linkajax').attr('href' , $('#category').val() );

Comment: May be like this - $('#category').val() + '.html'; what is the file name?

Comment: for example, T635.html

Comment: umm so it is $('.linkajax').attr('href' , 'T' + $('#category').val() + '.html' ); // I suppose number is in drop down.